# Browsers ignoring CSS rules

Tags: css

I am experiencing that some of my CSS rules are being ignored by Firefox, IE and Safari, while it looks right in Chrome, which I have developed for. 
I have hard refreshed, cleared the browser cache, used computers that never visited the site before and browsershots. Furthermore, I cleared CSS and JS in the cache management. Checking the CSS files I can see that the browsers are refering to old versions of the CSS files that does not match what I uploaded to the server. Why are the browsers loading old CSS versions?
My website is: http://www.thirstforgreat.com/merchandise.html

Comment: Did you try to access the page with an Private/Incognito browser instance?

Comment: Yes, it is still displaying differently.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to delete all files under pub/static and then rerun `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`? It can re-generate the CSS and JS files.